# Ошибка в решении задачи sql

Tags: sql

Решаю следующую задачу на сайте sql-ex.ru: Найдите корабли, сохранившиеся для будущих сражений; т.е. выведенные из строя в одной битве (damaged), они участвовали в другой, произошедшей позже.
Есть такие таблицы: Battles (name, date) и Outcomes (ship, battle, result)

Написала такой запрос:

```
SELECT temp.ship
FROM (SELECT ship
 FROM Outcomes JOIN Battles 
 ON name = battle
 WHERE result = 'damaged')AS temp
WHERE EXISTS(
 SELECT ship
 FROM (Outcomes JOIN Battles 
 ON name = battle
 WHERE date > temp.date AND temp.ship = ship
 )
)
```

Но сайт выдает ошибку:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

С каким WHERE может быть проблема? В чем она заключается?

Comment: Попробуйте пробел перед AS поставить damaged') AS

Comment: @Eugene Evstafiev нет, это не помогло

Comment: Очень смущает строчка `FROM (Outcomes JOIN Battles` где в ней `select`

Comment: @Alex R. Да, проблема оказалась в этой строке в лишних скобках. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за скобок и отсутствия атрибута во вложенном запросе, ниже я указал комментарии

```
    SELECT temp.ship
    FROM (SELECT ship
    FROM Outcomes JOIN Battles 
    ON name = battle
    WHERE result = 'damaged')AS temp
    WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT ship
    FROM (Outcomes JOIN Battles --Не понятно для чего открывается скобка
    ON name = battle
    WHERE date > temp.date AND temp.ship = ship -- в вложеном запросе temp нет атрибута temp.date
    ) --Не понятно для чего закрывается скобка
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь DISTINCT в самом первом SELECT
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH b AS(
 SELECT *
 FROM outcomes o JOIN battles b ON o.battle=b.name
 )
SELECT DISTINCT b1.ship FROM b b1
WHERE b1.result='damaged' AND EXISTS(
 SELECT b2.ship FROM b b2
 WHERE b2.date>b1.date AND b1.ship=b2.ship
)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT temp.ship
FROM (
   SELECT ship, date
   FROM Outcomes JOIN Battles  ON name = battle
   WHERE result = 'damaged'
)AS temp

WHERE EXISTS(
 SELECT ship
 FROM Outcomes JOIN Battles ON name = battle
 WHERE date > temp.date 
 AND temp.ship = ship
)
```

Это исправленный запрос, что написан выше. Он принимается системой на основной базе, но не принимается на проверочной.
Я считаю что можно написать запрос проще. Мой вариант:

```
SELECT o.ship
FROM outcomes o JOIN battles b ON o.battle=b.name
WHERE result NOT IN ('damaged')
AND 
EXISTS( 
   SELECT ship FROM outcomes JOIN battles ON battle=name
WHERE ship = o.ship
AND b.date>date
AND result IN ('damaged')
   )
```

И мой запрос тоже не проходит проверку на проверочной базе.
В чём может быть причина, пожалуйста подскажите.

PS ссылка где проверяю: https://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите.